# How can my code tell if it's inside a Queueable context?

Tags: asynchronous, context, queueable-interface

To go with the new [System.Queueable](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_queueing_jobs.htm) interface, I'm looking for the analogy of:

- `System.isBatch()`
- `System.isFuture()`
- `System.isScheduled()`

Is there a `System.isQueued()` or something?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Spring '16 brings us a new method:

`System.isQueueable()` which takes care of this requirement.

[releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/spring16/release-notes/rn_apex_new_classes_methods.htm](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/spring16/release-notes/rn_apex_new_classes_methods.htm#rn_apex_new_classes_methods_changed_classes)

**As of Spring '16, `isBatch()` does NOT return `true` from inside `Queueable` implementation.**

---

[image]

Comment: How did you get round the 'Method is not implemented.' Error? Sandbox?

Comment: @TimChadwick raise a case to Salesforce and ask them to turn the good stuff on.

Comment: Haha right'O ta

Comment: But how do you distinguish between being in a batch job and a queued job? :)

Comment: @kbentsen `if (context instanceof QueueableContext) ...`

Comment: Was kinda hoping for something that is outside the scope of the execute method or doesn't use the instance of QueueableContext. Basically I have a utility method that may be called synchronously or during a queued job, and it'd be nice to know within said method if the current context is queueable or not. You did give me an idea for a work-around, but it'd still be ideal to have something like System.isQueueable()

Comment: What is the workaround to use before the isQueueable() is available?

Answer (score 0):

I think that better is option is use this query, to veryfy if your class is in the queue

```
SELECT Id, ApexClassId from AsyncApexJob WHERE JobType = 'Queueable' AND Status = 'Queued' AND ApexClassId in (SELECT Id FROM ApexClass WHERE NAME = 'Imp')
```

Regards